# The image of an object under a subfunctor

Tags: category-theory

[image]Let $C$ be an additive category and $X$ is an object in $C$, $G$ is a functor in 
$(C^{op},Ab)$. $H$ is a subgroup of $G(X)$.

Define $G_{H}(C)$ to be the set of all $a$ in $G(C)$ such that $G(f)(a)$ in $H$ for all $f : X \to C$.

In particular, $G_{H}(X)$ consists of all the $a$ in $G(X)$ such that $G(g)(a)$ in $H$ for all $g : X \to X$.

***I want prove that  $G_{H}(X)=H$***, the inclusion in one direction is obvious just by taking $g$ to be the identity of $X$, which shows that $G_{H}(X)$ is contained in $H$.

Moreover, I have proved that for any subfunctor $F$ of $G$, $F(X) \subseteq G_H(X)$ implies that $F \subseteq G_H$. This conclusion maybe helpful?

Comment: How is $H$ defined?

Comment: I have completed the definition of $H$.

Comment: May I ask you if you have any idea of this question?@Martin Brandenburg

Answer (score 0):

The claim is wrong. Take any subgroup of the underlying additive group of a right module, which is not a submodule. This gives a counterexample where $C$ has one object, because then $C$ "is" a ring, $G$ "is" a right module over this ring, such that the action of $G$ on morphisms is right multiplication.

Comment: But this comes from proposition 1.2 of Auslander's papar Functors and Morphisms determined by Objects, have I losted some information?

Comment: I have posted the original paper here, thank you for your edit before.@
 
Martin Brandenburg

Comment: @MooS thank you for your work